# How to expand a search icon on click and render a search bar component I already built in my code?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

[image]
[image]

So basically what I have is this green search icon, i want to be able to click it and render the search bar below, which is a component I built. I'd like to achieve something like this: https://codepen.io/ahmadbassamemran/pen/rNjMXqg but I do have a hard time to figure out how to achieve that. Styling wise, how to click the green icon and open the search bar input component, and by clicking outside of the search input, the search input itself closes ? now the problem is that if I click the green icon the search bar appears but if i click the search input the search input also disappear because the state is defined on the same container i believe. How can i achieve that the input closes only when i click outside of it and open the search bar only when the input is closed? Thanks a lot for any sort of clues or tips. This is my code where the green search icon is rendered:

```
const [isExtended, setIsExtended] = useState(false); // this is for the search icon


const extendSearch = () => {
  setIsExtended(!isExtended);
};




          <Nav>
            <h2 style={{ fontSize: '1.2em' }}>Add Time</h2>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex'}}>
              <SearchIconDiv onClick={extendSearch}>
                {isExtended ? <SearchIcon /> : <SearchBar/>}
              </SearchIconDiv>
              <div
                onClick={() => setShowModal((prev) => !prev)}
                style={{
                  marginLeft: '5px',
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  display: 'flex',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
              >
                <ClosingIcon />
              </div>
            </div>
          </Nav>
```

I used styled components:

```
  const Nav = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  top: 0px;
  /* text-align: center; */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
`;

const SearchIconDiv = styled.div`
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
`;
```

This is the full component for the search bar, including styled components:

```
 // react
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
// styled components
import styled from 'styled-components';
// framer motion
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
// moon loader, spinner
import MoonLoader from 'react-spinners/MoonLoader';
// isOutisideClick
import { useClickOutside } from 'react-click-outside-hook';
// icons
import { IoSearch, IoClose } from 'react-icons/io5';
import SearchIcon from '../../../Icons/SearchIcon';


const containerVariants = {
  expanded: {
    height: '20em',
    zIndex: '200',
  },
  collapsed: {
    height: '3em',
  },
};

const containerTransition = { type: 'spring', damping: 22, stiffness: 150 };

function SearchBar(props) {
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [parentRef, isClickedOutside] = useClickOutside();
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [contexts, setContexts] = useState([]);
  const [noContexts, setNoContexts] = useState(false);

  const isEmpty = !contexts || contexts.length === 0;

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.value.trim() === '') setNoContexts(false);

    setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
  };

  const expandContainer = () => {
    setExpanded(true);
  };

  const collapseContainer = () => {
    setExpanded(false);
    setSearchQuery('');
    setLoading(false);
    setNoContexts(false);
    setContexts([]);
    if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.value = '';
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isClickedOutside) collapseContainer();
  }, [isClickedOutside]);


  return (
    <SearchBarContainer
      animate={isExpanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'}
      variants={containerVariants}
      transition={containerTransition}
      ref={parentRef}
    >
      <SearchInputContainer>
        <SearchInput
          placeholder="Search for contexts"
          onFocus={expandContainer}
          ref={inputRef}
          value={searchQuery}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <SearchIconDiv>
          <SearchIcon />
        </SearchIconDiv>
        {/* <AnimatePresence>
          {isExpanded && (
            <CloseIcon
              key="close-icon"
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
              exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
              onClick={collapseContainer}
              transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
            >
              <IoClose />
            </CloseIcon>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence> */}
      </SearchInputContainer>
      {isExpanded && <LineSeperator />}
      {isExpanded && (
        <SearchContent>
          {isLoading && (
            <LoadingWrapper>
              <MoonLoader loading color="#000" size={20} />
            </LoadingWrapper>
          )}
          {!isLoading && isEmpty && !noContexts && (
            <LoadingWrapper>
              <WarningMessage>Start typing to Search</WarningMessage>
            </LoadingWrapper>
          )}
          {!isLoading && noContexts && (
            <LoadingWrapper>
              <WarningMessage>No contexts have been found</WarningMessage>
            </LoadingWrapper>
          )}
          {!isLoading && !isEmpty && (
            <>
              {/* {contexts.map(({ show }) => (
                <TvShow
                  key={show.id}
                  thumbanilSrc={show.image && show.image.medium}
                  name={show.name}
                  rating={show.rating && show.rating.average}
                />
              ))} */}
            </>
          )}
        </SearchContent>
      )}
    </SearchBarContainer>
  );
}

const SearchBarContainer = styled(motion.div)`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 25em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 200;
`;

const SearchInputContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 15px;
`;

const SearchInput = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #12112e;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    &::placeholder {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  &::placeholder {
    color: #bebebe;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  }
`;

const SearchIconDiv = styled.span`
  color: #bebebe;
  font-size: 27px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
`;

const CloseIcon = styled(motion.span)`
  color: #bebebe;
  font-size: 23px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: #dfdfdf;
  }
`;

const LineSeperator = styled.span`
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 2px;
  background-color: #d8d8d878;
`;

const SearchContent = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow-y: auto;
`;

const LoadingWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const WarningMessage = styled.span`
  color: #a1a1a1;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
`;

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to make 2 separate components with and without the text input field and setup an "onClick" event listener to toggle between the two.

Example:

```js
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

// this is to be put into the return part

{isActive? <ComponentWithInput/> : <JustTheIcon/>}
```

And the event listener function could be something like this:

```js
<JustTheIcon onClick={ ()=> setIsActive(true) }/>
```

Then use any animation library of your choice to animate the transition

Comment: Thanks Mukul, i thought about - but when i tried i had the problem where by doing:                 {isExtended ? <SearchIcon /> : <SearchBar />} you are in either the situation where the icon is present or you get the whole search bar (with the icon is present inside of it) - i put the same icons and the problem is that when i click the SearchBar input when the state is extended, i cannot search anything because I soon as I click the state goes back to isExtended(false)

Comment: Hi! Hope I'm not too late to answer back. I saw your code and the issue is `setIsExtended(!isExtended)`. I solved the issue and the code can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-wozniak-25ht1?file=/src/App.js